Is it possible to "copy" a Maven package from one registry to another?
I would like to separate my build and deploy phases into separate steps that can be performed in entirely separate environments (i.e. different VMs).
The motivation is credential security: to make sure the deploy phase (which needs access to the publishing credentials) runs in a pristine environment in a separate machine, reducing the risk that previous phases (or other commands performed prior to the build) maliciously modified the environment to leak the credentials to deploy to OSSRH, for example.
This would require that the "build" stage run mvn deploy -Pstaging (where the staging profile points to an internal "staging" repository).
NOTE: this "staging" registry wouldn't be used for SNAPSHOTs, but for actual releases. It would simply be a "handoff point" for the "build" and "publish" stages.
I expected that the "publish" stage could then simply pull the package from the registry (all the files, including signatures, etc) and then run mvn deploy:deploy (not just deploy since that would try to run the previous phases, too) to move the package onward to its final destination, the external registry.
However, I realized this doesn't work because deploy:deploy requires some metadata before it can publish (this is even in the plugin's FAQ):
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy 
(default-cli) on project XYZ: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the 
build artifact -> [Help 1]

I then found this answer that suggested using mvn jar:jar deploy:deploy, since jar:jar won't recreate preexisting jars, but will "populate the build context" (whatever that means).
However, when I tried that, jar:jar errors out with:
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!

// ...

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.2:jar (default-cli) on
project XYZ: Error assembling JAR: Manifest file: /xyz/target/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
does not exist.

Which I assume comes from the fact that the "publish" stage doesn't have access to the source code, just the JARs?
I even ran mvn package and inspected the resulting MANIFEST.MF to see if it'd be something I could auto-generate in the "publish" stage... but it's too complicated and I don't understand it well enough to recreate it flexibly (i.e. does the format change depending  on the version of jar:jar, for example?), and I don't know if jar:jar would then simply complain about something else anyway...
I noticed that the main .jar file contains the MANIFEST.MF and auxiliary .jars (sources, javadoc) have one that's basically empty... is it therefore reasonable to extract the main manifest and reuse it?

So, is this even possible? Is it possible for the "publish" stage to dynamically create a "build context" having only the artifacts that were sent by the "build" stage?
For example, is it possible to somehow successfully run mvn deploy:deploy (or equivalent) given
./target
├─ xyz-1.2.3-javadoc.jar
├─ xyz-1.2.3-javadoc.jar.asc
├─ xyz-1.2.3-javadoc.jar.md5
├─ xyz-1.2.3-javadoc.jar.sha1
├─ xyz-1.2.3.jar
├─ xyz-1.2.3.jar.asc
├─ xyz-1.2.3.jar.md5
├─ xyz-1.2.3.jar.sha1
├─ xyz-1.2.3.pom
├─ xyz-1.2.3.pom.asc
├─ xyz-1.2.3.pom.md5
├─ xyz-1.2.3.pom.sha1

(where xyz-1.2.3.pom has the configs to publish to the final destination)
